# Distant Access without changing network configuration ( VNC without port openning )

Tags: networking, vnc

I looking for a solution for have the same functionality as a VNC. But i can't change the network configuration, it must work without any interaction of the user ( except fill the parameter of a script and launching it )

The Box will have a internet acces, but we have to consider that all the port except 80. The box will running a linux of our choice. We own the box, and we can install what we want on it. But we ship it by mail, and then some no technical people receive it. 
- They dont have to open any port
- or changing any config

Any idea / input ? ==>

- not free web based solution like gotomypc, logmein ... ?
- kaboodleproxy for hosting a echoserver ?
- EchoVNC http://echovnc.sourceforge.net/fom-serve/cache/1.html

Thanks

Comment: What OS are the machines to be logged in to running? That makes a HUGE difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would a REVERSE VNC solution such as "UltraVNC SC" work for you?

We use it here all the time for technical support.

The client downloads a small .EXE (which DOES NOT install on the system) and simply clicks on the link of the person they want to connect to.  We use ports 80 and 443 (and others) all the time.

As an added bonus, the client is brandable.  Works VERY well for us.

Note:

This particular solution is Widnows Based.

---

UPDATE:

Since the Windows solution isn't a viable option for you my next recommendation would be a reverse SSH tunnel.  You can find instructions for how to do this all over the place but check this link out first:

http://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling

Comment: Immmmmm. I'm think UltraVNC SC look's great. I will test it right now.
So even if there is a firewall/router , no port to open ?

Comment: arg, windows based... too bad.

Comment: Thus, a reverse vnc seems to be the solution. I wait to more precision on captain segfault answer to mark as resolved.

Comment: @a.claval See my updated answer above about reverse SSH for a solution.

Comment: Finally, i will use a reverse VNC. Like explain in this how to : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=299489

Answer (score 2):

Can you install any sort of vpn software such as [openvpn](http://openvpn.net/) or [hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/vpn.asp?lang=en)?
If so just have the computer you are on connect to the vpn the vnc computer is on and connect to its vpn ip with your vnc viewer.

Comment: What you propose is : 
The client install a VPN 
A VNC

The server install a VPN too, 

we connect each other via VPN

Comment: +1 - without opening ports, a vpn is the next best solution. Both of the above solutions are relatively easy for a client to set up.

Comment: @a.claval When both the vnc server and vnc client are on a vpn they see each other as if they where on the same local network. No need for any port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

[www.logmein.com](http://www.logmein.com) works on port 443 and does it outbound from the server so you don't need to open anything up on the firewall.  If you can access an SSL site, then you can use this.

Works very well and they have a free version.  I use it for all my remote access now.

Comment: logmein.com works great for this but obviously must be preinstalled on the machine you wish to access

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use the port forwarding functionality of ssh; you could set it to connect to an sshd on port 80 of a machine you control and forward some random port on your box to port 22 on the customer's box.

That would allow you to ssh into the customer's box.

Replace port 22 with something else if you want to use a tool other than ssh for the actual access.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. 

The custumer machine have to do a ssh myMachine:80 .

myMachine run a sshd listening on port 80.

And then you lost me...how can i forward a port on my box to a distant network ?

Comment: ssh can open a reverse tunnel; it listens on port 12345 on myMachine (the destination) and forwards to port 23456 on the customer's box (the source). (For your values of 12345 and 23456)

Answer (score 0):

www.teamviewer.com

work on cross platform, Mac OSX and Windows ...etc
Don't need any port forwarding. However will need a little user interactive on the target computer. It will generate a set of ID password on every sessions.

Answer (score 0):

[PC File Transfer](http://www.pc-file-transfer.com/) works on port 443. A nice feature is account connection that works behind routers and firewalls, so you don't have to worry that your transfer could be interrupted and blocked.