# Hosting a echoServer

Tags: remote-access, vnc, echoserver

in a previous question, i made the conclusion that i will need something like gotomypc or logmein, but self hosting the echo server.
Is it a good idea ? Any experience of this ?

I'm looking for something who run on linux.

( [Distant Access without changing network configuration ( VNC without port openning )](https://serverfault.com/questions/43515/distant-access-without-changing-network-configuration-vnc-without-port-openning) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never done this before, but it appears as if you are able to do this with something like [this](http://echovnc.sourceforge.net/fom-serve/cache/6.html).

Personally though, I would just go with a VNC over SSH or X Forwarding if you are looking for a solid remote access system for Linux.  It's far easier to maintain, no real extra hardware to work with, and it works extremely well.  In the past I've used [dynamic DNS](http://www.dyndns.org), and [VNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) over [SSH](http://www.openssh.com/) to get to my [home Linux box](http://www.ubuntu.com/), and it worked fine.  Also, the SSH provides more than enough security for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the accepted answer in your previous question: Yes, I think using a reverse SSH tunnel is a good idea, coupled with a VNC-server, this should provide the access you require.